# Sidekiq with a Worker who fetches jobs from two queues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I would like a Worker to be able to fetch jobs from two queues, which each queue has a diferent priority.

Right now, my worker looks like this:

```
class OrderWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false, queue: :orders
end
```

But I want to have another queue with orders that have higher priority, and make the worker consume that other queue. Is that even possible with Sidekiq? If so, at the time that you do `OrderWorker.perform_async(...)`, how do you specify which queue?

Thanks!

Comment: Do [queue weighting or ordered queue processing](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#queues) not do what you need?

Comment: @colinm queue weighting would work as long as I can specify that a worker would work with two queues. I have a worker with a queue for sending emails, but then I need two additional queues for orders. I just need one more worker to focus on those two order queues.

Comment: That's exactly how weighting works. Each time you run `sidekiq` (whether on a traditional CLI or via a Procfile), you're starting one worker. If you pass weighting options on the command-line, they only affect the one worker they were passed to. You can specify that a single worker process any number of queues.

Comment: colinm, but then how do I enqueue a particular job to a particular queue? Usually you do MyWorker.perform_async(args). How do you tell it to enqueue it in a particular queue? Could you write an example as an answer, so I can accept it? I think it is really clear for you, but not for me right now.

Comment: I have the same question. I want one worker to process jobs from both a high priority and a low priority queue, and hopefully be able to enqueue a particular job to a particular queue.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass `queue` as an option:

```
OrderWorker.perform_async(:queue => 'high')
OrderWorker.perform_async(:queue => 'default') # default is 'default' anyway
```

`perform_async` and `perform_in` call method [push](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/8ceffc1eb3c61b9126cf445fcaae81e5e6d94116/lib/sidekiq/client.rb#L69), which has a `queue` argument among others.

Comment: Does this mean I don't have to specify a queue in the worker code as described [in the docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#queues)?

Comment: Not specifying the queue in the worker (ex: `sidekiq_options  queue: :high`) will put it in the 'default' queue.  Passing `:queue=> 'high'` as argument of `perform_async` overrides the `sidekiq_options` one.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Kudos for the link to the `push` code.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't know if sidekiq supports this, but if it was me, I'd probably just use inheritance for this since it's just plain Ruby.

```
class OrderWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
end

class HighPriorityOrderWorker < OrderWorker
  sidekiq_options retry: false, queue: :high_priority_orders
end

class LowPriorityOrderWorker < OrderWorker
  sidekiq_options retry: false, queue: :low_priority_orders
end
```

Comment: I don't know if this works, you might need to move the include line into the subclasses.

Comment: But this would mean that I need to declare two workers (in Heroku for example). I just want to have one worker who consumes from two queues. Just one queue has jobs with more priority than the other queue.